# How to set box filled color value in swift xcode

Tags: swift, xcode

How to set color code value in swift `UIColor.red`
With box of color filled with red.

example coding

```
label.textColor = UIColor.red // Coding 

label.textColor = a small box with color red filled??
```

Comment: Your question is unclear. Why do you want that?

Comment: `label.backgroundColor = .red` ?

Comment: did you asking for hex color code?

Comment: Are you looking for Color Literal?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The thing you're looking for is **`color literal`**.

1. Type `color literal` as a value of `label.textColor` and select `Color Literal` from the dropdown.

[image]

2. It will look something like this,

[image]

3. `Double tap` on the `white box` that appeared. A `color palette` will open like,

[image]

4. Select whatever `color` you want from the `color palette`. It will finally look something like,

[image]

Hence the box of color filled with red..

Comment: Yes I am for color literal! its helps me!